# How to model a television dial?

Tags: modeling, topology

I'm trying to model this dial and for some reason I'm totally stumped on how to do this without too many booleans and to make it smoother than the rest of the tv.  I've been watching tutorials, but the few I found were more how to make the a knob separately and from a side view rather than front (which is what I'm doing).

If you need the .blend I've attached it, but any simple example or tutorial suggestions would do...not trying to get anyone to do the work for me ;)

Here's the image:

[image]

And here's what I have so far with a boolean...I just have the feeling this is the wrong way to go about this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common way to do that is create a hole in the surface, add a circle into that space then fill in the gaps.

1 : **Subdivide** a plane and delete some of the inner vertices.

2: **Add** a circle with a vertice count the same as the number of vertices that now make up the inner edges of the plane.

3: Select both the circle and the inner edges of the plane, then using the **W** shortcut key open the **Specials menu** and choose **Bridge Edge Loops**.

4: Using the **Extrude** tool model the rest of the Dial.

5: Add bevels and or supporting edge loops, smooth….. etc  etc .

Note that if you intend to use a Subsurf modifier then aim to use a circle with less vertices than in my example below.

[image]

Check on Youtube for cutting holes in meshes. This is a good example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA

Comment: Nice one. We need more topology Q&A here. Beginners tend to attack such problems with booleans, based on the logic that real world sculpting mediums like clay work that way (just carve out or add to it!). I totally did this when I was starting out with 3D. I was really happy when I finally saw a tutorial that made topology click for me, and that marked a turning point in how I approached modeling. Because of this I am now a huge advocate of teaching topology (and I do). I am also still learning new things about it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this until now...wow this is definitely a cool way to go about it.  I do want to avoid too many boolean operations, so this is a great technique too.

Answer (score 0):

I would make another object with "P" and then edit it as I like. You can also apply smooth surface setting on the left (when its separate object)

Comment: Ahh that works nicely...now it doesn't affect the surround mesh.  Thanks!